# Implicit Broadcast in android Oreo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have a project which contains 6 apps. When one app receives a notification, other five apps also get notified through implicit broadcast receiver.

But In android Oreo implicit broadcast receiver is deprecated. So I can't notify other 5 apps together.

Is there anyway that I can do the same functionality in android oreo?

Comment: Just to flash some lights Read [This blog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html) . You may find a solution .

Answer (score 3):

Quoting myself, from [the blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html) linked to from [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085518/implicit-broadcast-in-android-oreo#comment87186942_50085518):

> If you are *sending* implicit broadcasts, you can break through the ban by
>   finding the receivers and sending individual explicit broadcasts instead:

```
private static void sendImplicitBroadcast(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
  PackageManager pm=ctxt.getPackageManager();
  List<ResolveInfo> matches=pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(i, 0);

  for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : matches) {
    Intent explicit=new Intent(i);
    ComponentName cn=
      new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
        resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);

    explicit.setComponent(cn);
    ctxt.sendBroadcast(explicit);
  }
}
```

> Unfortunately, this brings back the process churn, and if lots of developers
>   do this, there may be reprisals from Google. You might try introducing some
>   delay between the broadcasts, inside the loop, to spread out the impact. However,
>   this starts to get tricky if you spread it out over more than a few seconds
>   (e.g., do you now need an `IntentService` and a `WakeLock`? what if your process
>   is terminated before the broadcast loop is completed?).